# Sharepoint workflow ignores approval condition

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a custom workflow (created through SharePoint Designer) that starts with an approval task and then sends emails to different people if the submission is approved.

I have an if clause in the workflow that goes like

```
If Current Item:Approval Status equals 0;#Approved
    Email <users>
```

The problem I have is that it seems to ignore the if statement (at least when the item is rejected) and emails anyway. I tested this with one submission where I got the approval task and hit the Reject button, but I still got an email that should have only been sent if approved.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Does the Approval Status not tie to what I think it does?

Answer (score 1):

The Approval Task outputs to a list item ID. You need to utilize that list item ID to look up to your tasks list for that particular item and evaluate the outcome.  If that is approved then email people.

Comment: That seems a little inconvenient but I'll check that out and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: This can't be true.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. The TaskId of the new created task is not the SharePoint ID, it is a Guid.